# how to make URL pattern accept variable arguments in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

my title may not be very clear. 
The problem I am facing now is:

my view passes arbitrary keyword arguments to another `view`.
This view handles with what info(keyword arguments it gets)

This is the example of `search` feature I am implementing.
Each user will have a list of `Saved Searches`. when they click on any one of the items in `Search list`, they will be directed to a different view that process the information it receives

In the `Searches model`, I have defined a get_absolute_url method that constructs the URL pattern of each of these search (based on models in the field).

```
my model:

    class Searches(models.Model):
        SELLER_CHOICES=(('OWNER','owner'),
                        ('DEALER','dealer'),
                        ('BOTH','both'), )
        #search_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        make = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
        model = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
        keywords = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
        max_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        min_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        max_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        min_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        pic_only = models.NullBooleanField()
        search_title_only = models.NullBooleanField()
        owner_dealer_all = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=SELLER_CHOICES,verbose_name='owner/dealer')
        class Meta:
            #managed = False
            db_table = 'Searches'
            verbose_name_plural = "Searches"

        def __unicode__(self):
            return "%s %s %s-%s" %(self.make,self.model,self.max_year,self.min_year)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('postings.views.detail',args=[model_to_dict(self.object)])

view:

    class SearchListView(ListView):
        model=Searches

template:

    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block content %}

    {% for obj in object_list %}
    <p><a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}">{{ obj }}</a></p>
    {% endfor %}

    {% endblock %}
```

you can see from the image, when I click the `your searches`, I get error;

```
Reverse for 'postings.views.detail' with arguments '({'owner_dealer_all': u'DEALER', 'pic_only': True, 'make': u'toyota', u'id': 3, 'min_year': 1990, 'min_price': 4000, 'user': 1, 'keywords': u'hybrid', 'search_title_only': True, 'model': u'prius', 'max_price': 20000, 'max_year': 2012},)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Basically, I dont know how to handle this in the URL pattern.

OR
IF THIS IS A BAD DESIGN, PLEASE PLEASE SUGGEST A SOLUTION
[image]

Comment: please let me know if anything is unclear, so that I could elaborate on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to have all the variables in the URL, then you need to pass the variables as params of a GET query, so your URL will look like this:

```
http://example.com/search?owner_dealer_all=DEALER&pic_only=True&make=toyota&id=3&min_year=1990&min_price=4000&user=1&keywords=hybrid&search_title_only=True&model=prius&max_price=20000&max_year=2012
```

But, I would strongly suggest that you keep that URL as separate from the `Search.get_absolute_url` result, as the latter is supposed to point to the actual model. So have that function return something like:

```
http://example.com/search/23465
```

where the number is the ID for your `Search` model instance. In that view, get all the saved details and make a search on them. If you actually don't need the data in your URL, simply opt for the latter version only.